# evaluation about Exp[] and Complex problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
Exp[I*Pi*0.75]*Exp[I*Pi*0.75]
Exp[I*2*Pi*0.75]
```

the results are:

```
-2.22045*10^-16 - 1. I
-1.83697*10^-16 - 1. I
```

I know it is basic, but I cannot figure out why the results are not the same.

Comment: It is the result of using machine precision. Use [`arbitrary-precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) `Exp[I*Pi*0.75\`15]*Exp[I*Pi*0.75\`15]` and 
`Exp[I*2*Pi*0.75\`15]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bob Hanlon said, it's a result of errors accumulating due to the limited and untracked precision of machine precision numbers. Compare:

```
With[{x = 0.75}, {Exp[I Pi x] Exp[I Pi x], Exp[I Pi x]^2, Exp[2 I Pi x]}]
```

Where we test 3 equivalent expressions and get 3 very slightly different results.

If we substitute in an arbitrarily precise 0.75 of any particular precision though, the results are no longer distinguishable other than the last one has approximately twice as many digits of precision.

```
With[{x = 0.75`10}, {Exp[I Pi x] Exp[I Pi x], Exp[I Pi x]^2, Exp[2 I Pi x]}]
```

Typically real or imaginary parts on the order of `$MachineEpsilon` are likely negligible. Unless you are expecting or concerned about the existence of small real/imaginary parts, there is typically little harm in ignoring them. If you need to verify their existence, arbitrary precision arithmetic is usually sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. maybe I can ignore it to get more speed.

Comment: You may also be interested in `Chop`.

Comment: I will try to see the results, thanks